# Component returns array of div not rendering inside the parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having hard time to figure out why my component HistoriesList inside the div  of WorkitemHistory is not rendering its content, although I see the console.log to print. My code is:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useContext } from 'react';
import { fetchHistories } from 'stores/actions';

import { ProjectContext } from 'AppContexts/ProjectContext';

export default function WorkitemHistory({ isOpened, closeModal, curWorkitem }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(ProjectContext);

  const { histories } = state;

  const modalRef = useRef(null);
  const $modalEl = useRef(null);
  const jQuery = window.$;

  useEffect(() => {
    $modalEl.current = jQuery(modalRef.current);

    $modalEl.current.modal({
      keyboard: false,
      backdrop: 'static',
      show: false,
    });

    if (isOpened) {
      $modalEl.current.modal('show');
    }
  }, [isOpened, $modalEl]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () =>
      await fetchHistories(dispatch, { workitemId: curWorkitem }, true))();
  }, []);

  const handleModalClose = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $modalEl.current.modal('hide');
    $modalEl.current.on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      closeModal();
    });
  };

  if (histories.isFetching) return 'Loading..';
  console.log('Workitem histories', histories);

  return (
    <div
      className='modal fade'
      id='workitemHistoriesModal'
      tabindex='-1'
      role='dialog'
      ref={modalRef}
    >
      <div className='modal-dialog modal-lg' role='document'>
        <div className='modal-content'>
          <div className='modal-header'>
            <button className='close' type='button' onClick={handleModalClose}>
              <span>&times;</span>{' '}
            </button>
            <h3 className='modal-title'>Work Item - History</h3>
          </div>
          <div className='modal-body'>
            <div className='alert alert-info'>
              Below you find a list of changes that were applied to the
              workitem.
            </div>
            <div>
              <HistoriesList histories={histories} curWorkitem={curWorkitem} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='modal-footer'>
            <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={handleModalClose}>
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function HistoriesList({ histories, curWorkitem }) {
  const rows = histories.byId[curWorkitem];

  if (rows === void 0 || rows.length === 0) return null;

  console.log(
    'Type of',
    rows.map((row) => row.author)
  );

  return rows.map((row) => <div key={row.author}>{row.author}</div>);
}
```

Attached the  screenshot you will see there that the modal is empty. It seems very simple, but I am now tired to figure out what is the reason of this weird thing. Please help. Let me know if I need to provide any more information.

[image]

**EDIT**

Added a `console.log` as asked in the comment.

```
function HistoriesList({ histories, curWorkitem }) {
  const rows = histories.byId[curWorkitem];

  console.log('HistoriesList', rows);

  if (rows === void 0 || rows.length === 0) return null;

  console.log(
    'Type of',
    rows.map((row) => row.author)
  );

  return rows.map((row) => <div key={row.author}>{row.author}</div>);
}
```

[image]

**Edit2**

I did the code change like this..

```
function HistoriesList({ histories, curWorkitem }) {
  const rows = histories.byId[curWorkitem];

  console.log('HistoriesList', rows);

  if (rows === void 0 || rows.length === 0) return 'hello';

  console.log(
    'Type of',
    rows.map((row) => row.author)
  );

  return 'world';
```

chrome console proves that it is coming after the `if`, but modal has no text change.

[image]

Comment: Probably CSS issue, Just inspect the DOM and check if it is rendered in elements tabs.

Comment: put a `console.log(rows)` before the `if (rows === void 0 || rows.length === 0) return null;` to see if the `rows` are being reset

Comment: @tsfahmad I did check, the `<div>` is empty.

Comment: @TaghiKhavari Added the console.log as you asked.

Comment: Probably due to the model being controlled by your jquery, and then you try to update the content of a jquery box. Try removing jquery and do everything in react.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you return object is not right, try this one

```
return (<>
          rows.map((row) => <div key={row.author}><span>{row.author}</span></div>)
      </>);
```

Comment: see my edit. and your answer is nothing added except <span>.

Answer (score 0):

Replace you function with this one and then let me know whether its works or not

```
function HistoriesList({ histories, curWorkitem }) {
      const rows = histories.byId[curWorkitem];
    
      console.log('HistoriesList', rows);
    
      if (rows === undefined || rows.length === 0) return 'hello';
    
      return (<>rows.map((row) => (<div key={row.author}><span>{row.author}</span></div>)) 
      </>);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your codes by removing the jquery use effect. Sometimes Jquery+React gives you undesirable effect because of dom manipulation.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useContext } from 'react';
import { fetchHistories } from 'stores/actions';

import { ProjectContext } from 'AppContexts/ProjectContext';

export default function WorkitemHistory({ isOpened, closeModal, curWorkitem }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(ProjectContext);

  const { histories } = state;

  const modalRef = useRef(null);


  useEffect(() => {
    (async () =>
      await fetchHistories(dispatch, { workitemId: curWorkitem }, true))();
  }, []);

  const handleModalClose = (e) => {
    
      closeModal();

  };

  if (histories.isFetching) return 'Loading..';
  console.log('Workitem histories', histories);

  return (
    <div
      className=`modal fade ${isOpened ? 'in' : ''}` //<-- u only need this
      id='workitemHistoriesModal'
      tabindex='-1'
      role='dialog'
      ref={modalRef}
    >
      <div className='modal-dialog modal-lg' role='document'>
        <div className='modal-content'>
          <div className='modal-header'>
            <button className='close' type='button' onClick={handleModalClose}>
              <span>&times;</span>{' '}
            </button>
            <h3 className='modal-title'>Work Item - History</h3>
          </div>
          <div className='modal-body'>
            <div className='alert alert-info'>
              Below you find a list of changes that were applied to the
              workitem.
            </div>
            <div>
              <HistoriesList histories={histories} curWorkitem={curWorkitem} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='modal-footer'>
            <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={handleModalClose}>
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function HistoriesList({ histories, curWorkitem }) {
  const rows = histories.byId[curWorkitem];

  if (rows === void 0 || rows.length === 0) return null;

  console.log(
    'Type of',
    rows.map((row) => row.author)
  );

  return rows.map((row) => <div key={row.author}>{row.author}</div>);
}
```

Comment: I solved it by using portal. Keeping everything inside the component had it some unknown effect

Comment: it still give u problem when remove jquery?